# "destroy" ng-if once expression is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering if is possible to unbind/destroy `ng-if` once its value is true?

I created tree structure with recurrence directive and each of branches has `<div ng-if="visible">` which keeps tracking if element needs to be rendered. The problem is that the solution increase number of watchers because every `ng-if` creates new one. Once the `ng-if` expression became `true` it won't change so watch can be removed, is there any way to "destroy" `ng-if` in that case?

Comment: You can grab the source code and lift that directive code in order to modify it to do what you want

Comment: [ng-if](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if using angular 1.3+ you can do

```
<div ng-if="::visible">
```

Which will remove the expression from angular watchlist and essentially no watches on it. Use this for any single binded expressions in your app. Keeps your watch count low and digest cycles faster.

Comment: I tried that, the problem with this solution is that once parent scope has assigned value all children will inherit it so by default I have to assign false value to every scope variable.

Comment: Suppose the value of "visible" changes from undefined to false and then to true, the watcher will be dropped when it changes to false, right? So this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @evenstar how about initiating with false in controller? and then wait for it to turn to true- this should work. BTW the above solution works for the question asked  i.e single binding not multiple binding!. if you are looking at multiple states you cannot single bind. You would have to remove that watcher manually after it turns true.

Comment: @VikasBansal no problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [bindonce library](https://github.com/pasvaz/bindonce), which happens to have a `bo-if = "condition"` directive attribute, which is described as:

> equivalent to `ng-if` but doesn't use watchers

So is somewhat similar of what you want to achieve.