# Ionic 4: “destroy” ngIf once expression is true

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm looking for something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002656/destroy-ng-if-once-expression-is-true/34004126), but for Ionic 4:

> I am wondering if is possible to unbind/destroy ng-if once its value
>   is true?

Comment: You could be using hand managed componentFactoryResolver to create, insert, destroy components

Comment: could you elaborate, please?

Comment: There is a general approach to kick off https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 0):

Not the exactly answer to the question, but it might help someone who is looking for this solution:

I was trying to use ngIf to show a header only once, for a set o items, but only if there were items to show... What I finally did was the following:

```
        <p [hidden]="!showedOnce">Some header</p> 
        <div *ngFor="let task of tasks; let taskIndex = index">
            <span *ngIf="taskIndex > 0">{{setShowedOnce()}}</span>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>{{task.title}}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
        </div>
```

And in the component:

```
showedOnce: boolean

ngOnInit() {
    this.showedOnce = false
}

setShowedOnce() {
    this.showedOnce = true
}
```